# case statement is not updating all values in sql

Tags: sql

Trying to update 'Office' flag to update all of the rows for the same claim if it meets the criteria. The issue is it updates 1 row but not the other.

table A

| ID | invoice_ number | maker_no | Office |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 11111 | 45 | N |
| 456 | 11111 | GS | Y |

table B

| ID | invoice_ number | maker_no | Office |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 11111 | 45 | **Y** |
| 456 | 11111 | GS | Y |

code:

```
SELECT c.invoice_number
      ,c.maker_no
      ,CASE WHEN c.maker_no IN('GS','77') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Office
FROM claims c
```

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: That's a select, not an update

Comment: And it's a case _expression_, not statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a window function:

```
SELECT c.invoice_number, c.maker_no,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.maker_no IN('GS','77') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) OVER (PARTITION BY c.invoice_number) AS Office
FROM claims c;
```